# Setup a Cron Job to pick latest file and email

Tags: bash, cron

Pretty simple question.

I have a cron job that runs a mysql query everyday at midnight and produces a csv file say user_analytics_2012-03-11.csv. So everyday a new file keeps getting created with a new date stamp.

I am trying to setup a new cron job that runs after this job and picks up the latest csv file and emails it to me.

I've managed to do this by hardcoding the file name and it works fine:

`mutt -s "Number of users logged in" -a /tmp/user_analytics_2012-03-11.csv example@gmail.com < /tmp/message.txt`

Now how do I make this setup to automatically pick up the latest file.
Thanks a lot

EDIT

I tried the following and it seems to work - Is this the right way to go about it.

`mutt -s "Number of users logged in" -a /tmp/user_analytics_$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).csv example@gmail.com < /tmp/message.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you have mailx installed (`man mail` for your system's specifics):

`mysql_command | mail -s "Number of users logged in" example@gmail.com`

This bypasses creating a file in the first place.

Comment: Its not a simple mysql_command - its a php script that queries multiple tables and creates the output csv file - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your directory only contains these files the easiest would be listing the contents, sorted by creation/modification date and picking the first one:

```
mutt -s "Number of users logged in" -a /tmp/$(ls -t | head -n 1) example@gmail.com < /tmp/message.txt
```

Comment: Thanks - but the folder contains other files as well.